# API Facebook - Usuario genérico

Tags: php, api, facebook

Estoy creando una aplicación web y quisiera que publicara automáticamente un post en una página de Facebook cuando un usuario conteste unas preguntas de un formulario. He creado una aplicación de Facebook y he conseguido que se añada un comentario a la página de Facebook desde la aplicación web pero me exige hacer login con mi usuario de Facebook para poder añadir el comentario. 
Me gustaría saber si existe la posibilidad de utilizar algo como un usuario genérico para que el proceso de publicación en Facebook fuese transparente para el usuario, sea usuario de Facebook o no lo sea. Es decir, que la publicación en Facebook fuese automática sin necesidad de hacer ningún login. He estado buscando en la documentación de la API de facebook pero no he encontrado nada similar y también he buscado por Internet pero no he sido capaz de encontrar información.
Un saludo y muchas gracias

Comment: Hola M. Rrtega y bienvenido. ¿Con qué lenguaje estás trabajando? ¿Podrías ser más específico e explicar qué has intentado? Un saludo.

Comment: Hola @m-rrtega, bienvenido a Stackoverflow en Español. Te comento que esta comunidad no es un sustituto de Google, por lo que debes replantear tu pregunta agregando un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) de tu problema. También te invito a que consultes la guía sobre ["cómo hacer una buena pregunta"](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hola Toledano, muchas gracias. Perdón si no me he explicado suficientemente en mi mensaje. Estoy utilizando php. Evidentemente no puedo aportar ningún ejemplo dado que la pregunta simplemente es si es posible automatizar que se añadan los comentarios a un página que es mía sin que el usuario se tenga que logar, bien usando un usuario genérico o bien, como plantea (o creo entender que plantea) Jasilva. No me importa utilizar mi usuario, ya digo que he conseguido enviar un mensaje a mi página con mi usuario, lo que necesito es que sea un proceso totalmente transparente para el usuario. Un saludo

Comment: Perdón Miquel Coll, no había visto tu respuesta. Creo que ya lo he expuesto en otras respuestas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final he conseguido mas o menos hacer lo que quería. Lo explico a grandes rasgos porque, después de las vueltas que he dado, no sabría explicarlo mas claramente porque creo que he dado con la solución por casualidad. 
Lo que hago es publicar como PAGE y con un token permanente mediante una aplicación. Es decir, el usuario no tiene que logarse, de echo puede no ser usuario de Facebook ya que es la aplicación la que envía el mensaje y lo publica en la página. Siento no poder explicar esto mejor pero quizá le pueda servir a alguien. Entre nosotros ¿me lo parece a mi o es que la documentación de Facebook es bastante pobre y carente de ejemplos prácticos?
Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es que cuando un usuario conteste tu cuestionario se publique algo en su muro, el **deberá** hacer login obligatoriamente a tu webapp. Por seguridad no hay forma de que puedas publicar algo en su muro sin su autorización.

Si lo que quieres es publicar en tu muro o muro de tu webapp. Lo que puedes hacer es dejar las credenciales de facebook en tu app y desde ahi hacer el login, pero a tu cuenta (o de tu app) y se publicaria el resultado ahi

Comment: Hola Jasilva Muchas gracias por tu contestación. No, no quiero publicar en su muro, quiero publicar en una página que es mía, es decir, la segunda opción que planteas. Ando muy perdido porque la documentación de la API me resulta muy complicada de entender y me parece que tiene pocos ejemplos ¿sabrías decirme como hacer lo que comentas? Parece que es precisamente lo que estoy buscando. Un saludo y muchísimas gracias

Comment: @M.Rrtega ¿En que lenguaje estas trabajando?

Comment: Estoy utilizando php.

Comment: Lo lamento pero no conozco PHP, ya edite la pregunta para agregar la etiqueta y que alguien pueda auxiliarnos

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta Jasilva. Utilizo php pero si mi problema se resolviera así podría tratar de utilizar JavaScript.